# React get props in child component for inner function use

Tags: reactjs

i got a component `A`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Gmap from '../global/gmap.component'

class RandomPlace extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Gmap address={this.state.random.location} />
```

which renders among other things, the `Gmap` component:

```
class Gmap extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="gmap-component">
        <p>{this.props.address}</p>
```

This `<p>{this.props.address}</p>` is well displayed and updated when i hit a "reload" button on component `A`. At this point, the React Chrome extension shows well the props' address content. And sees it being updated well on the "reload" action.

Problem is, i cant seem to be able to reach the props property `address` in the internal functions of my component `Gmap` like `componentDidMount()` or `aCustomFunction()`.

I have tested this:

```
componentDidMount () {
    console.log('gmap did mount')
    this.setState({address: this.props.address})
    let x = this.props.address
    let y = this.state.address

    console.log(x)
    console.log(y)
```

With a constructor at the top of the class:

```
constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      address: 'xx'
    }
```

But nothing shows up. I am new to React and sure i am missing something pretty basic but cant see to spot it.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you see at logs?

Comment: I got `undefined` and `xx`.

Comment: It's best to inspect props and state in render just before you return your jsx, also react chrome dev tools help a lot with debugging such cases.

Comment: Yes i do try to use react chrome dv tools, and it all looks fone there, updating fine.

Comment: I trying this on [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/71305/), logs looks like correct, isn't it?

Comment: @Andrew yes, it looks simple and fine, like it should. I basically have the same code here, split between files and it just wont give me the address with `this.props.address` in Gmap. Getting frustrated.

Comment: show me export of gmap

Comment: Here's the Gmap component: https://github.com/kevinch/boracomeraonde/blob/feature/mapComponent/src/components/global/gmap.component.js and it's being called by the random component: https://github.com/kevinch/boracomeraonde/blob/feature/mapComponent/src/components/places/random.component.js

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking how to call a custom function on your child component? If so,

```
  <Gmap address={this.state.random.location}  ref={(map) => { this.map = map; }} />
```

Then

```
this.map.aCustomFunction()
```

Comment: No, i am wondering on how to use the location passed via prop in the child (Gmap) element's functions. Though the display itself works in the render.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure, but i think it's going like:

1. In your component A, `address={this.state.random.location}` set from the state, as you see.
2. random object fill with call getRandomPlace() in componentDidMount().
3. So what's going on: at first you render Gmap component you have prop address there with undefined, because on component A didn't call componentDidMount() yet.
4. Then in component A trigger componentDidMount you get filled object "random" and yuor component Gmap recive normal prop addres, with no indefined. And rerender component with this new adderss prop, but your componentDidMount() in component Gmap has already invoked and doesn't trigger more...

If i'm right, you can set at component A

```
constructor(){
    super();
    this.state={
        random: {location: "some test value"}
    }
}
```

and you will see this "some test value" instead undefined in your console log.